# Determining $a$ and $b$ so $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere. $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}+1)$, for $x>0$ and $f(x)=ax+b$, for x $\le 0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}+1)$, for $x>0$ and

$f(x)=ax+b$, for $x \le 0$.

How can I determine $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)$ is differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}$?

Afterwards I also have to check if $f(x)$ is *continuously differentiable* respectivle even *differentiable twice* on $\mathbb{R}$. I think I might get that done on my own, but if you also want to help with that task I appreaciate it. But first of all I need help determining $a$ and $b$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\lim_{0^+}\frac {f (x)-f (0)}{x}=$$

$$\lim_{0^+}(x\sin (1/x+1)-b/x) $$

but
$$x|\sin (1/x+1)|\le x $$
thus
$$\lim_{0^+} x\sin (1/x+1)=0$$
and $b=0.$

the left derivative should be zero, which gives $a=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why $b=0$ though. Can you explain that?

Comment: @lolan496 If $b\ne 0$, the left limit will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

First we need that $f$ is continuous at $0$. To this end determine $b$ such that

$ \lim_{x \to 0+0}f(x)= \lim_{x \to 0-0}f(x)$.

Then determine $a$ such that

$ \lim_{x \to 0+0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x \to 0-0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$.